# Kubernetes docker volume mounting option

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a docker image with the option for property file like,

```
CMD java -jar /opt/test/test-service.war 
--spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties
```

I use the `-v` volume mount in my `docker run` command as follows.

```
-v /usr/xyz/props/application.properties:/conf/application.properties
```

I am not sure how to achieve the same thing in Kubernetes.
I use minikube to run kubernetes in my local mac.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That should be an **[host path volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath)**, illustrated with this example pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```